# Name and related theory for game: "n-th Player to respond wins"

Tags: game-theory

What is the classic name of the game "The N-th player to respond wins"? What are general strategies for the case when the number of total players is not known (or maybe there's only a prior on the number of players)? What theory exists on this topic?

Assume that there is only a single simultaneous round: each player $p$ chooses a time $t_p$ to respond, with no knowledge (other than a prior, perhaps) of when the other players respond.

If necessary to make the problem well-defined, let's also assume a maximum time $T_\max$, beyond which no response will win, as well as $P$ total players, discrete time steps. The hardest, most interesting case, is when no player can observed when other players have responded. Another case is if the game is repeated, and all players can observe all responses after the game is over.

Comment: What are the rules of the game? Every player secretly determines a point in time where he "responds"? Or all players can see how many players have already responded? Or all players can see how many players have responded until an hour ago?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've updated the question with some clarifications

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry for the bump, I'm curious if you have or know of any resources that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand what a prior would be in this context. It seems that the problem is likely ill defined due to the lack of a time scale.

Comment: @joriki hm, you're right it might be ill-defined. Let's assume there's a finite $T_{\max}$, and there are $P$ total players.